# How to get service using Dependency Injection (Autofac) in Quartz.Net Job

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, quartz.net

I am using Autofac for Dependency Injection and Quartz.net for scheduling the jobs. When I try to access the service from the Quartz.Net job using the below code, the job is not executed.

```
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public SendMailTask(IEmailSender emailSender, ILogger logger)
{
   _emailSender = emailSender;
   _logger = logger;
}
```

The services are registered at the startup of the application.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder(); builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());   
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController)));
builder.RegisterType<EmailSender>().As<IEmailSender>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultLogger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerRequest();
```

any help would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: There's a package for that: [Autofac.Extras.Quartz](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.Quartz/). The documentation is thorough, so read it carefully.

Comment: yes I have referred the sample code, but those code are for .net core. do you have any reference for mvc.net?

Comment: Don't expect to copy and paste it, then. Understand what it's doing and then apply what you've learned. You haven't shown the scheduler setup in your question so there's no way to help with that.

Comment: Thank you, I have figured out the issue and now the jobs are triggered.